# PayPal and ASP.Net : how to communicate with PayPal and have "intelligent return url"

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm building a website to start a little service, and I wanted to add payment integration with PayPal.

I have already made the Business account and created couple of buttons that are. I couldn't find a way to specify a custom return URL, both in case of success and failure.

So then I came to the conclusion that what I really need is to have the user providing his personal details (first and last name, address, postal code, city, email and mobile number) that I will also provide to PayPal so I can know :

- how has made the payment
- to which email address I will send an automatic email confirming subscription

The way I see the workflow is :

1. The user provide his personal details
2. The user select a subscription plan
3. User is redirected to PayPal with his information already filled (except for credit card information)
4. User is redirected to the website in anycases
5. If payment is successful, an email is sent to the user confirming subscription

I don't know exactly what solution to use and also didn't found useful information with coding examples on this topic. I'm currently stock on finding a solution to make my app communicating with PayPal.